# VIS JS - Instead of Fa or Glaphicons use other icons - icoMoon

Tags: angular, vis.js

Using VIS package in Angular we have implemented VIS chart with VIS chart.

We are using different icon library, which is icoMoon.

We have generated website required icons from icoMoon website with keywork ico and used as below as menu icons -

ex 1) icoMoon class working in website as -

Question - i) How we can use above ico-icouser class to below nodes ?
           ii) Also tried to use icon code for class in below nodes 
              as '\e97e' , but when used this it automatically converts 'e97e' and not get applied at all.

ex 2) vis reference code as here.......

```
const nodes = [
      { id: 0, font: { multi: true }, x: -40, y: -40, label: '"<b>CUSTOMER</b>\n<i>text text</i>', group: 'customer'},
      { id: 1, label: 'IBM 1', size: 20, group: 'users' },
      { id: 2, label: 'WINDOWS', size: 20, group: 'users' },
      { id: 3, label: 'APPLICATION', size: 20, group: 'usergroups' },
      { id: 4, label: 'VPN', size: 20, group: 'vpn' },
      { id: 5, label: 'PARTNER B', size: 20, group: 'usergroups' },
      { id: 6, label: 'PARTNER C', size: 20, group: 'usergroups' },
      { id: 7, label: 'PARTNER D', size: 20, group: 'usergroups' },
      { id: 8, label: 'APP SUPPORT 1', size: 20, group: 'users' },
      { id: 9, label: 'APP SUPPORT 2', size: 10, group: 'users' }
    ];
    // create an array with edges
    const edges = [
      { from: 0, to: 2 },
      { from: 0, to: 1 },
      { from: 0, to: 3 },
      { from: 2, to: 4 },
      { from: 1, to: 4 },
      { from: 3, to: 4 },
      { from: 4, to: 5 },
      { from: 4, to: 6 },
      { from: 4, to: 7 },
      { from: 7, to: 8, label: 'lock' },
      { from: 7, to: 9 }
    ];
    // create a network
    const container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');
    this.data = {
      nodes,
      edges
    };
    this.options = {
      groups: {
        vpn: {
          shape: 'icon',
          icon: {
            face: 'FontAwesome',
            code: '\uf023',
            size: 50,
            color: '#f57376'
          }
        },
        usergroups: {
          shape: 'icon',
          icon: {
            face: 'FontAwesome',
            code: '\uf0c0',
            size: 50,
            color: '#57169a'
          }
        },
        users: {
          shape: 'icon',
          icon: {
            face: 'FontAwesome',
            code: '\uf007',
            size: 50,
            color: '#aa00ff'
          }
        },
        customer: {
          shape: 'icon',
          icon: {
            face: 'FontAwesome',
            code: 'e97e',
            size: 50,
            color: '#193744'
          }
        }
      }
    };
    const netcall = new Network(container, this.data, this.options);
```

Answer (score 1):

We are able to use custom font icons in VIS , by using SVG file path
shape: 'image',
image' = '/path/to/svg.svg';

Comment: path to svg? is it relative or absolute?